# How do you transfer a user account to another computer?

Tags: windows, user, transfer

I am traveling and I am using a laptop which is not mine (because I left my own laptop at my home). I got too carried away with the borrowed laptop and I made a user account on it.

I do not want to make a new account when I get back to using my own laptop, so I need to transfer my account form borrowed laptop to my laptop. Does anyone know how?

Comment: Which OS you are using on your laptop and which one is on borrowed one?

Comment: Yes you can use the same method as this built in feature for Vista too.

Answer (score 7):

I assume you are working on Windows-7 and then its much easy to transfer the User profile. Just click on **Start** button and then type in search box **Windows Easy Tranfer** and click on it or you can run it as an **admin**.

[image]

Now click on `Next`

[image]

Now select the third option as you have to take it along with you.

[image]

Now select the second option after this Windows will scan for the files of all users on this PC and then you can copy them in your USB or external HDD.

**Note** You can use this method for transferring files form Windows Vista to Windows-7 too because this feature also available there.

If you want to transfer **User Profile** from XP to Windows-7/Vista then download [Easy Transfer](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-CA/windows7/products/features/windows-easy-transfer).

For Windows XP you can download this [guide](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=how%20to%20transfer%20a%20userprofile%20form%20one%20pc%20to%20other&source=web&cd=5&ved=0CG8QFjAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cpsb.org%2Fsystem%2Fdataprocessing%2FFile%2520and%2520Settings%2520Transfer%2520Wizard%2520instructions.pdf&ei=xoPQT86JG87LrQfcqqygDA&usg=AFQjCNHowj8il2OiOkL2eV-U6rXzYV_dKg).